# After importing KML to Google Maps, point is showing in Antartica

Tags: xml, google-maps, kml

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a very simple version of my KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark>
<name>SUNSHINE CHEVRON</name>
<description>HIALEAH</description>
<Point>
    <coordinates>25.872066,-80.282852,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

When I try to create a map and import this point, it shows up in Antartica.

Any thoughts? I validated the file using http://kmlvalidator.com/, and it returns with no errors.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [documentation on coordinates](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates), the coordinates are in longitude,latitude,[altitude]

> ```
> A single tuple consisting of floating point values for longitude, latitude, 
> and altitude (in that order). Longitude and latitude values are in degrees, 
> where:
>
>    longitude ≥ −180 and <= 180
>    latitude ≥ −90 and ≤ 90
>    altitude values (optional) are in meters above sea level
> ```
>
> Do not include spaces between the three values that describe a coordinate.

So they should be:

> ```
> <coordinates>-80.282852,25.872066</coordinates>
> ```

(Assuming you want the placemark in [Florida](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkmltest_SUNSHINE_CHEVRON_a_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=25.871581,-80.282593&sspn=1.235634,1.691895&t=m&z=19))

Comment: That is exactly right. It worked when I flipped the lat and long and kept the ,0. Thanks!