# Specific lat lng in KML can't be shown

Tags: kml, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to show the following coordinates in kml but it can't be shown correctly with Google Maps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>Invercargill Rocks!</name>
    <description>Go there and see!</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>43.006687,144.391647</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

I use the following site to check if the kml works: 
http://display-kml.appspot.com/

It works with the following coordinates but doesn't work with mine.

- (works) 168.34693908691406,-46.416322245553296
- (doesn't work) 43.006687,144.391647

Could you somebody tell me why?

Comment: 144.39 is not a valid value for a latitude (KML coordinates are in the order longitude,latitude)

Comment: Thanks, geocodezip. I didn't know the order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [After importing KML to Google Maps, point is showing in Antartica](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081160/after-importing-kml-to-google-maps-point-is-showing-in-antartica)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As geocodezip mentioned, the correct order has to be lng and lat.